# Make bootup of Ubuntu 20.04 faster

Tags: boot, 20.04, systemd, services

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 with 4 Gb memory (dual boot with Windows 10) in a Dell Vostro 2520 laptop (i3 - 3rd gen). The bootup for the ubuntu takes up quite a bit of my time and hence I was looking I anyone can help out a bit. Also, I am trying to understand the process, so a bit of explanation would help too. The output of `systemd-analyze critical-chain` is:

> ```
> graphical.target @1min 24.160s
> └─multi-user.target @1min 24.160s
>   └─apache-htcacheclean.service @48.581s +95ms
>     └─apache2.service @32.585s +15.972s
>       └─network.target @32.581s
>         └─NetworkManager.service @20.327s +12.253s
>           └─dbus.service @20.320s
>             └─basic.target @20.192soot 
>               └─sockets.target @20.192s
>                 └─snapd.socket @20.189s +2ms
>                   └─sysinit.target @20.040s
>                     └─swap.target @20.040s
>                       └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-8eb9d29f\x2d3720\x2d4f9b\x2d99ad\x2dcbfc7fb65561.swap @19.949s +91ms
>                         └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-8eb9d29f\x2d3720\x2d4f9b\x2d99ad\x2dcbfc7fb65561.device @19.948s
> ```

The output of the first screen from the `systemd-analyse blame` is:

> ```
> 49.196s plymouth-quit-wait.service                                               
> 17.305s networkd-dispatcher.service                                              
> 16.183s accounts-daemon.service                                                  
> 15.972s apache2.service                                                          
> 14.888s dev-sda1.device                                                          
> 12.308s avahi-daemon.service                                                     
> 12.253s NetworkManager.service                                                   
> 11.889s polkit.service                                                           
> 11.612s udisks2.service                                                          
>  9.597s snapd.service                                                            
>  8.841s dev-loop3.device                                                         
>  8.688s apport.service                                                           
>  8.643s grub-common.service                                                      
>  8.582s ModemManager.service                                                     
>  8.479s dev-loop0.device                                                         
>  8.269s dev-loop2.device                                                         
>  8.231s dev-loop1.device                                                         
>  7.969s teamviewerd.service                                                      
>  7.838s preload.service                                                          
>  7.580s grub-initrd-fallback.service                                             
>  7.393s rc.local.service                                                         
>  7.292s atd.service                                                              
>  7.227s e2scrub_reap.service                                                     
>  7.226s ftsprhv.service                                                          
>  7.224s gpu-manager.service                                                      
>  7.144s rsyslog.service                                                          
>  6.813s lm-sensors.service                                                       
>  6.530s pppd-dns.service                                                         
>  5.457s systemd-udevd.service                                                    
>  5.366s switcheroo-control.service                                               
>  5.040s thermald.service                                                         
>  5.038s systemd-logind.service                                                   
>  5.029s wpa_supplicant.service                                                   
>  4.356s bluetooth.service                                                        
>  4.165s apparmor.service                                                         
>  3.958s systemd-journal-flush.service                                            
>  3.633s systemd-resolved.service
> ```

I have tried a few other solutions which exist, and have managed to bring down to a significant extent, but I believe that there is further room for improvement.

Comment: It's all right there in your output: 20 seconds to mount your disk (check your /etc/fstab). 12 seconds to start up NetworkManager before login (that's optional). Another 15 seconds to start up your Apache webserver (perhaps a forgotten experiment?). Use the Search box at the top of the page to look up how others have addressed these common questions.

Comment: Thanks. I have actually looked up about the Apache webserver and needless to say I have very little idea about it. Is it something important? Will it affect my system if i stop it? And since you have mentioned that network manager is optional, I had tried to disable it using `sudo systemctl disable NetworkManagerwait-online.service`  but it still figures here. any help?

Comment: You have three projects: The EASY project is to search your memory for why YOU installed an Apache web server. It didn't come with Ubuntu. If you're not using it, then uninstall it. The INTERMEDIATE project is to fix your disk mounting. Mounting is done by UUIDs, and the usual culprit is that one of your UUIDs is wrong. Learn how to use `blkid` and `/etc/fstab` to find and correct the wrong UUID. The ADVANCED project is to learn how to disable Network Manager during boot; to start it instead after login. That one is very not-easy.

Comment: Thanks again for those pointers. I uninstalled apache webserver (but did not get any significant gains in terms of bootup time). Reading about the second and third options you pointed.

Comment: After each change, you should be running `critical-chain` again to see what changed.